# Powershell - Return Azure Blob Size by first split string value

Tags: azure, powershell

So I am trying to list the contents on an Azure blog container size, I can get how much storage is being used as a whole. What I trying to do is break it down, by the first position of the filename.

And this is my sad attempt. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
$ResourceGroup = "RG"
$StorageAccountName = "SAN"
$ContainerName = "CN"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount `
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
  -Name $StorageAccountName
$Context = $storageAccount.Context 

$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Context 
$length = 0
$Blobs | ForEach-Object {$length = $length + $_.Length }

#$Blobs.Name.Split("_",2)[0]

$Blobs | Select-Object Name, Length 

$TotalSize = [math]::Round(($length / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024),2)
Write-Host "Total Size: $TotalSize Terabytes"
```

**Current Output.**
ABCD_History_20221127_110045            9306112

ABCD_History_20221204_110052            11010048

ABCD_History_20221211_110045            10616832

EFGH_20220327_110201                    48562176

EFGH_20220403_110159                    46596096

Total Size: 29.63 Terabytes

**Desired Output**
ABCD                                    30932992

EFGH                                    95158272

Total Size: 29.63 Terabytes

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-9.2.0):

```
$ResourceGroup = "XX"
$StorageAccountName = "rith"
$ContainerName = "rithwik"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount `
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
  -Name $StorageAccountName
$Context = $storageAccount.Context 

$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Context 
$length = 0
$Blobs | ForEach-Object {$length = $length + $_.Length }    
$Blobs | Select-Object Name, Length
```

[image]

After that used below code to get required Output:

```
foreach($emo in $blobs)                                                
 {
 $BlobName=$Blobs.Name.Substring(0,3)
 }  
$Target = @()
foreach($emo in $BlobName)
 {
 $bn=$emo
 $x=0
foreach($b in $blobs)
 {
 if ($b.Name -match $Bn) 
 {
 $x=$x+$b.Length
 }
 }
 $out = $bn + $x
 $Target += $out
 } 
$Target | select -uniq
```

[image]

If you want 4 letters in output give 4 in `substring` command instead of 3.

If you space between name and length you use like below in place of  `$out = $bn + $x` in for loop:

```
$out = $bn +" "+ $x
```

[image]